# Hibernate keeps trying to update when it should insert and fail the flush()

Tags: spring, hibernate, oracle12c, ojdbc

When i'm going to save an object which has composite id following error was given.
This was happened in oracle sql 12c sever, but not in 11g server.

> Blockquote
>   org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
>       at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:85)
>       at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.verifyOutcome(Expectations.java:70)
>       at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.checkRowCounts(BatchingBatcher.java:90)
>       at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
>       at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
>       at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:114)
>       at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:109)
>       at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareBatchStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:244)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2525)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2478)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2805)
>       at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:114)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:268)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:260)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:180)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1206)
>   ..
>   ..

When i check the Trace I encounter that hibernate fire an insert query and after that fire an update query for the same record with same values.

I defined the composite key as follow.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"><hibernate-mapping package="package.of.the.class">
    <class name="ClassName"  table="TABLE_NAME">
        <composite-id>
            <key-property name="variable1_string" column="col1" />
            <key-property name="variable2_string" column="col2" />
            <key-property name="variable3_date" column="col3" />
            <key-property name="variable4_date" column="col4" />
            <key-property name="variable5_string" column="col5" />
        </composite-id>

        other properties...

    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

I checked values when records are being saving by debugger, but there was no duplicate values for the ID columns.

Library versions are as follow.

- Hibernate 3.5
- ojdbc6
- spring-aop 4.3.1
- spring-core 4.3.1
- spring-jdbc 4.3.1
- spring-orm 3.2.2
- Oracle sql server 12c

Please, someone tell me what has gone wrong?

Comment: For starters stop mixing versions of spring. Never mix versions of a framework, regardless of the framework.

Comment: That is true @Deinum, but this is not the right time to upgrade that library, because lot of classes have dependencies with that library. All are working fine with 11g database. Only this save() is failing when pointed to 12c database.